# Use variable name fadeIn and Prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I want to prepend this variable "logText" and make it fade in at the same time.

```
var logText = today + ":" + " " + document.getElementById("textBox").value + '<br>\n';
$("#logContent").prepend(logText);
```

Here is what I got but it doesn't work.

```
var logText = today + ":" + " " + document.getElementById("textBox").value + '<br>\n';
$("#logContent").prepend($(logText).fadeIn('slow'));
```

Comment: Try to `fadeIn` a `#logContent` box , like this `$("#logContent").prepend(logText).fadeIn('slow')`

Comment: I'm pretty sure logText isn't a domElement, so it's not working against the jQuery selector.

Comment: The function is still working but doesn't fade. :(

Comment: So do I need to make up HTML element then make it equal to logText?

Comment: Show us your html and css relevant parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("<p>" + today + ": " + $("#textBox").val() + "</p>")  // new DOM Node
              .css("display", "none")    // hide it
              .prependTo("#logContent")  // prepend it to #logContent
              .fadeIn("slow");           // fade it in slowly
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPbyU/)

Comment: Wow I wish I were as good as you are. Guess I will have to keep study!!! Thank you.

Comment: Oh I just noticed that now my date which is the var "today" disappear, it says "today" instead.

Comment: Ups :-( I've messed up the quotes and didn't notice the failure. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#logContent").prepend(today + ": " + $("#textBox").val() + '<br>').fadeIn('slow');
```